# Adding field in custom deserialization constructor

Tags: vb.net, serialization

I have one class implementing ISerializable interface, with one private field that is saved and retrieved:

```
Protected Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
    _name= info.GetString("_name")
End Sub
```

Now, I want to add a new private field, but since it did not exist previously, when I try to open a serialized object I get an exception when trying to get this field, in the custom deserialization constructor. The solution I've come up with is to use a Try...Catch block, as follows:

```
Protected Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, _
                 ByVal context As StreamingContext)
    _name= info.GetString("_name")
    Try
       _active= info.GetBoolean("_active")
    Catch ex As Exception
        _active= False
    End Try
End Sub
```

It works, but it seems a bit messy to me, moreover because I will have to add a new Try...Catch block for each new field I want to add.
Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527478/2651069) t0mm13b says that "There is a more neater way to do this in 2.0+ upwards". Any ideas about what is he talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in method that allows you to first determine if a particular value exists (e.g. `Exists`).  There is also no `Get...` method which simply returns `Nothing` if the value does not exist (e.g. `TryGet`).  However, the one way that you can do it which avoids the potential for exceptions is to use a `For Each` loop to iterate through all of the values in the `SerializationInfo` collection.  For instance:

```
For Each i As SerializationEntry In info
    Select Case i.Name
        Case "_name"
            _name = DirectCast(i.Value, String)

        ' ...
    End Select
Next
```

**Note:** It may be surprising to you that you can use a `For Each` loop on a `SerializationInfo` object, since it does not implement the `IEnumerable` interface (nor the generic equivalent).  However, `For Each` in VB.NET actually works with any object that has a public `GetEnumerator` method.  So, even though it leads to some confusion, objects don't technically need to implement `IEnumerable` in order for you to iterate through them with a `For Each` loop.  Since the `SerializationInfo` class *does* expose a public [`GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, you can iterate through it with a `For Each` loop.